# CRUD operations using asp.net Icontroller Versus using asp.net ApiController inside my asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

If I need to build a web application that implement functionalities related to managing an Medical hospital institution. That application include functionalities to add, update, delete, search and retrieve patients, medical visits, etc.

**So I am confused on which approach to follow inside my ASP.NET MVC web application**, either to have my controller classes inside my asp.net MVC.

1. Derived from IController to perform the CRUD operation

**OR**

1. Derived from ApiController to perform the CRUD operations

**SECOND question** is there an approach that is taking over the other, and what are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to generate classical HTML pages from your controllers, use the MVC ones. If what you want to return to a client is some kind of serialized data (XML, JSON, ...), use Web API controllers since these make it easier, regarding e.g. content negotiation.

See also [Getting started with Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, but there are some examples on Microsoft web site that uses Controller which are derived from ApiController to return razor views rather than JSON.

Comment: That's definitely possible. However, I find it easier to generate HTML from MVC controllers. By the way you can of course combine both types of controllers in a single project, using e.g. MVC controllers for HTML reporting and Web API for the API endpoints returning XML or JSON to generic clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use both. Nothing stops you to use good old Controller to do CRUD in JSON and MVC is capable of doing it. However, you do not get all the nice features of Web API such as content negotiation, message handlers, media type formatters, etc.

If you do not need any of Web API specific features, then use MVC. But **on the long run, Web API will be a better investment as I believe adoption will rocket soon.**

Comment: then does this means that Web API is taking over MVC ,, or they both will work together in the future???

Comment: Use Web API to expose services and MVC to return rendered views.